# Where Query In One-One RelationShip in EF Repository Pattern

Tags: entity-framework, relationship, repository-pattern, one-to-one

Following is my database architecture, three entities:

**Load**

- ID_Load
- From
- To
- Bids[]

**Bid**

- ID_Bid
- ID_Load
- Amount
- Load
- Order

**Order**

- ID_Order
- Status
- Amount
- Bid
- Load

Load and Bid : One to Many       -- Load can receive multiple Bids

Order and Bid  : One to One      -- A single bid will be mapped with a order

Order and Load : One to One      -- An order can have only one Bid

As you can see above I don't have ID_Load or ID_Bid properties in the order Entity as EF generate these automatically in the database, so the properties for these two fields are not added in the Order Entity

I am currenlty using Repository pattern with **Code First** in my project.

Now I want to get the Order information by ID_Load/ID_Bid (as there is a one to one relationship of Bid-Order and Load-Order table)

I don't want to run any SP or Select query in the application, but having issue while doing this.

If I run SQL I will have to write following query:

Select * from Order Where ID_Load = 123

Or

Select * from Order Where ID_Bid = 123

What is the alternative of this in EF/Repository Patterns in such situations.

Can anyone please help me with this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Get order by Bid ID:

```
long bidId; // Id of Bid
var order = dbContext.Orders.Single(o => o.Bid.ID_Bid == bidId);
```

Get order by Load ID:

```
long loadId; // Id of Load
var order = dbContext.Orders.Single(o => o.Load.ID_Load == loadId);
```

If Bid and Load are optional for Order, use `SingleOrDefault` instead of `Single`. `Single` will throw an exception if the queried item does not exist, `SingleOrDefault` will return null.

Alternatively, if you need to load the Bid using its ID anyway:

```
var bid = dbContext.Bids.Find(bidId);
var order = bid.Order;
```

This can be optimized by forcing eager loading:

```
var bid = dbContext.Bids.Include(b => b.Order).SingleOrDefault(b => b.ID_Bid == bidId);
var order = bid.Order;
```